# Accessing html files which are contained inside another jar file in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jar, jetty

I am using Spring MVC with embedded jetty server. From my controller I am returning a jsp page basically a [return "home"]. But if this home.jsp is kept inside another a jar file Ex [helpPage.jar] and my application is [app.jar] which has dependency of [helpPage.jar].

What  should i return form my controller (inside app.jar)  to access that "home.jsp" page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly discouraged.

double-nested deep compressed content is not supported.

This isn't even supported on Jetty Distribution, it will unpack nested content into a work/temp directory to then serve them without the double-nested issues.

Would advise updating your build to flatten the web base resources to a single deep compressed location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But we have lot of static html pages (> 200MB )compressed into a jar and deployed in nexus. While running my application I download that jar from nexus and then extract those pages into folder. After that things work pretty well. But this extraction is taking a lot of time which is making the build process very very slow. So we were planning to download that jar and directly serve the pages from the downloaded jar

Comment: Access to doubly nested compressed jar content is also a source of memory leaks.  One of the primary reasons Jetty doesn't support it.  Not to mention it makes serving static content about 8x slower as there are no NIO benefits available in that scenario.  You will use on-average 4x the memory per static file resource to serve it using this configuration.